# How size of this structure comes out to be unexpected?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)

Hi all,

i  wanted to know how size of below structure comes out to be 24.As per my calculation it should be 20.and one more thing is there any way this structure is taking size of its variable t into account??

Please ignore any syntax error and i am on 32 bit machine

```
 struct structc
{ 

char        c; 
double      d; 
int         s;
} t;

main()
{
printf("sizeof(structc_t) = %d\n", sizeof(t)); 
}
```

Comment: No @Jon its not duplicate what did u suggest.

Comment: @ArtoAle t needs sizeof(char) + 7 byte padding + sizeof(double) + sizeof(int) = 1 + 7 + 8 + 4 = 20 bytes.

Comment: Yeah, right, but you didn't consider final 4 bytes padding :)

Comment: @AMIT: It is indeed a duplicate. Also, it's meaningless to pull numbers out of thin air and then wonder why they don't match reality. What is your compiler? Only its documentation can answer the "why 24?"  question definitively.

Comment: yaa @ArtoAle that is what i want to know final 4 bytes padding why its needed and for which variable??

Answer (score 6):

The size of the struct includes padding bytes between is members due to packing alignment, which is compiler- and architecture-dependent (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Typical_alignment_of_C_structs_on_x86) for an example)

**Update:** Not surprisingly, this question is a dupe. For a better answer, see [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/119123/50079).